# How to prevent other developers destroy our Parse server data

Tags: ios, parse-server

I deploy a `Parse` server on Heroku. But when I create a demo app, I use Charles to capture network, I see that it show `Application ID` and `Client ID`. With that informations, others developer can access data in my class, write junk data, create junk classes with junk data, ... How can I prevent that?

I can prevent them write junk data, or delete my data, by implement `beforeSave`, `beforeDelete` in Cloud Code. But what about when they read data, and when they create junk class with junk data?

Comment: Have you looked at http://blog.parse.com/learn/secure-your-app-one-class-at-a-time/ ?

Comment: But I use my Parse server, it doesn't have UI to set CLP (class level permissions). And it can't prevent people create junk class

Comment: Do you mean other developers on your team?

Comment: @SimonBengtsson I mean other developers not in my team, they may be developer from my competitor company. They want to destroy us, make my server slow, spam my Parse server by create junk class and junk data

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's not that much you can do if the other developers are on your team and they have the same access to the app as you. If you mean users however the first thing I would do to secure `parse-server` is to set [class level permissions](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#security-class-level-permissions). As there is no dashboard yet this has to be done manually. Checkout the `_Schema` collection in your database. It will have a field `_metadata` that will look something like this:

```
// Public read, private write
"_metadata": {
  "class_permissions": {
    "get": {"*": true},
    "find": {"*": true},
    "update": {},
    "create": {},
    "delete": {},
    "addField": {},
    "readUserFields": [],
    "writeUserFields": []
  }
}
```

There is also security options based on roles, users and objects. These can be set in code as before and you can see how the change affects the objects. Here is some example values:

```
{
  "_id": "0CjkfC3MCO",
  "_acl": {
    "*": {"r": true},
    "role:store": {"w": true}
  },
  "_rperm": ["*"],
  "_wperm": ["role:admin"],
  "_updated_at": ISODate("2016-02-25T02:26:49.179Z"),
  "_created_at": ISODate("2015-08-07T19:47:42.008Z")
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I mean they are developer from competitor

Answer (score 0):

To avoid junk class creation, set allow user class creation to false in your parse server settings/environment.

With sensitive objects/classes configure ACL access - you can set read/write access there.

Disable anonymous user in parse server settings to only registered users can use the server.

What regards to data, validate all data in beforeSave/afterSave triggers.